# How to change images using foreach in php and javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, laravel

I want to change image on button click. Please check what I am doing:

```
 <div>
 <?php $fetchImageArray = array();?>
   <?php foreach($photos as $photo): ?>
     <?php
       $fetchImageArray[] = $photo;
      ?>
   <?php /*<img src="<?= $product['image']; ?>" alt="<?= $product['title']; ?>" class="img-thumb-detailModal"> */?>

    <?php if($i == 0):?>
       <img  src="<?=$photo; ?>" alt="<?= $product['title']; ?>"
             class="img-thumb-detailModal" id="theImage"
             style="width:280px;height:360px;position:absolute;">

   <?php else:?>
       <img  src="<?=$photo; ?>" alt="<?= $product['title']; ?>"
             class="img-thumb-detailModal" id="theImage"
             style="width:280px;height:360px;position:absolute;visibility: hidden;">

  <?php endif;?>

  <?php
   $i++;
  endforeach;?>


  <a class="stackButton sx" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</a>  <!-- Right Button -->
  <a class="stackButton dx" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</a> <!-- Right Button -->
</div>

<script>

var slideIndex = 1;
var i = 0;
function plusDivs(n)
{
    var i += slideIndex;

    document.getElementById('theImage').src="<?=$fetchImageArray[i];?>"; //$fetchImageArray[2]
} 
</script>
```

@ `$fetchImageArray[2]`, if I use 2 instead of `$fetchImageArray[i]` it changes the images but I have to pass `$fetchImageArray[i]` because I am storing the source path in an array and here I am retrieving it by passing index but then it is not working. If it starts work then the code will be fine.

Kindly suggest what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Before even attempting to read your code, I should mention one thing that a lot of new coders don't understand when using PHP ... PHP is a "pre-processor", does it's thang on the server and once it processes the file, it then sends HTML to the browser - there is no two way communication in simple PHP - so for instance in `plusDivs` function, the value of `var i` is in no way related to the `i` in `$fetchImageArray[i]`

Comment: your code, although it might work under some circumstances, is wrong, especially considering best practices. You should read more on server and client-side scripts... Please do...

Answer (score 0):

You should not mess around with php and javascript as stated on comments, from your code it should be done with javascript/jquery, you can have idea like this:

```
<style>
  img {
    width:280px;
    height:360px;
    position:absolute;
  }
  .hide {
    display: none;
  }
</style>
<div>
   <?php foreach($photos as $photo): ?>
       <img src="<?=$photo; ?>" alt="<?= $product['title']; ?>" class="img-thumb-detailModal hide" id="theImage">
  <?php endforeach; ?>

  <a class="stackButton sx" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</a>  <!-- Left Button -->
  <a class="stackButton dx" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</a> <!-- Right Button -->
</div>

<script>
  varar slideIndex = 1;
  showSlides(slideIndex);

  // Next/previous controls
  function plusDivs(n) {
    showDivs(slideIndex += n);
  }

  function showDivs(n) {
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("img-thumb-detailModal");
    if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1} 
    if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.display = "none"; 
    }
    slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  }
</script>
```

I didn't test with my code but you will have idea on your mind, for more info you can refer to this: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can't use it like that.

```
   function plusDivs(n)
    {
        var i += slideIndex;

        document.getElementById('theImage').src="<?=$fetchImageArray[i];?>"; //$fetchImageArray[2]
    }
```

Because, $fetchImageArray[i] doesn't exists. Php doesn't know javascript var i.

But, you can do some little trick. You load $fetchImageArray to javascript as array.

You can use laravel @foreach($array as $key => $element) and @endforeach, you don't have to use  everytime, or even at all. Look at [Laravel Templates](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/templates)

```
function plusDivs(n)
    {
        var i += slideIndex;
        var fetchImageArray = [
           @foreach ($fetchImageArray as $key => $image)
             {{$image.','}}
           @endforeach
        ]

        document.getElementById('theImage').src=fetchImageArray[i];
    }
```

But you should check if your "i variable" is in your array. Or there would be some error.

Hope, I understand your question.